# How can I enable PIE/ASLR in my monotouch application?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, aslr, pie-chart

There is an option in XCode Build Settings called "Don't Create Position Independent Executables". This is straight-forward to enable here.

However, I'm using MonoDevelop and MonoTouch to develop my application, and I cannot find the equivalent setting there. I've tried passing the -fpie flag to the compiler, but doesn't seem to work. When I examine the compiled binary using otool, it does not have the PIE flag set.

Please help.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you need to create a PIE executable anyway?

Comment: Just one additional security measure.PIE enabled seems to be the default when building from XCode. I just cannot seem to figure out why its not default from MonoTouch. Or how to enable it in MonoTouch

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MonoTouch doesn't currently support position independent code, when we AOT the managed code we generate position dependent code.

We may fix this in the future, but right now it's not a priority.

**Update**

Apple has just started warning about non-PIE enabled executables when publishing to the App Store. This will obviously shift our priorities.

**Update 2**

We have a potential fix which is going through testing / QA (but no firm release date yet).

**Update 3 (2015/03/21)**

This was fixed a long time ago.

Comment: Yep I just got a warning on an app submission. From the tone of the email it looks like Apple may require PIE executables in the near future :/  @Rolf Any ideas what kind of effort this will involve for Xamarin and when PIE capability will be available?

Comment: @PaulDB: Apple started warning about it yesterday, and we have just started looking at it, so we do not have a timeline yet.

Comment: Is there anything on the roadmap for this yet for Xamarin Studio and Xamarin.iOS?

Comment: @DaleSmith: we have a potential fix which is going through testing/QA (but no firm release date yet).